# How to convert the vertical text to horizonatl form | Linux |

Tags: linux, shell

I have a scenario where I want to convert the vertical text in file to horizontal format into new file

The text in file is :

```
(A)
(B)
(C)
(D)
(E)
(F)
```

output should be like below in new file - filedemo.txt

```
(A),(B),(C),(D),(E),(F)

At last after (F) ,  => ',' should not come
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose column to row without separator in the end](//stackoverflow.com/q/58382633) and many others

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose column to row without separator in the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382633/transpose-column-to-row-without-separator-in-the-end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is:

```
paste -sd, fileinput.txt > filedemo.txt
```

[`paste`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/paste.html) is a posix utility to merge lines.

`-s` makes it read consecutive lines from one file and concatenate them.

`-d,` set's the separator as the comma.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that with paste. Nifty.